# How do I link a user to a new form page after submitting a form in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am trying, very unsuccessfully, to send a user to a new form page "Payment" after they have completed an "Order" page. Basically, there are two models for "Payment" and "Order", and after the first form, I don't want to go to 'orders/3' or whatever the newly created show action is. Instead, I want to go to /payments/new so that I can fill out my credit card info.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%# <%= f.hidden_field :cart_id, value: @cart.id%> 
    <%= f.input :first_name %>
    <%= f.input :last_name %>
    <%= f.input :address %>
    <%= f.input :city %>
    <%= f.input :state %>
    <%= f.input :zip_code %>
    <%=f.input :total_cost, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => params[:total_cost]}%>
    <%=f.input :cart_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => params[:cart_id]}%>
    <%=f.input :completed, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => "no"}%>
  </div>

  <%= form_tag new_payment_path, :method => :get do %>
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit">Checkout » </button>
  <% end %>
  
  <%= link_to new_payment_path({total_cost: params[:total_cost]}) do %>
    <button type="submit">"hello" </button>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

As you can see, I have two buttons at the bottom that I'm trying to merge into one, but every possible way to do this seems to cause an error. Is there some specific way of getting that link_to function's button type to connect with the rest of the form?

Apologies in advance if this is quite basic. My understanding of Ruby on Rails is rather weak but I'm trying hard to quickly correct this and learn as much as I can.

Comment: Why not just redirect to that page in the controller after an order create, in the OrdersController create method that is?  Just submit the form, if it save or is successful redirect to the new payment page.  Should be straightforward paths (I assume).

Comment: Ah that worked. I guess I just assumed that redirecting the user is something that the view should handle, since that's where link_to functions generally occur. Thank you so much!

Comment: I mean there are many different ways to do it.  But this way you could wrap it inside the `if save` block and only redirect if it saves, or direct back to errors, otherwise you have to handle all that with JS or something.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do your form without a button leading to payment page and instead in your 'order' controller 'create' method after processing the form use 'redirect_to LINK_TO_PAY' page. You can add some sort of attributes in the session to recognize the user and associate it with payment afterwards.

Comment: Yep that's what I ended up doing almost exactly. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the best way to handle this is to add the redirection to the 'create' method in the orders controller. I ended up just sticking the path "/payments/new" into the redirect_to function and it all worked swimmingly.

```
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to "/payments/new", notice: "Order was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
        
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
      
    end
```